# Popen doesn't run my exe

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, exe, popen, launch

*(Python 3)*

I'm trying to use popen in  a little script to run an executable

The executable is at :
https://github.com/Gorov/FCM_nips_workshop

I'm on windows and by modifying a little the github README command I can run easily the program using

```
RE_FCT ../data/SemEval.train.fea.sst ../data/SemEval.test.fea.sst predict.fea.fullnerpair.onlyne.txt ../data/vectors.nyt2011.cbow.semeval.filtered 5 0.005
```

The exe is RE_FCT and all the following text is just arguments

So using a terminal it works just fine and display informations while runing

But when I try to make it run using my little python script, it does nothing. Actually something seems runing but it never ends and doesn't display anything

Here's my code

```
import subprocess


command = ['RE_FCT', '../data/SemEval.train.fea.sst', '../data/SemEval.test.fea.sst ', 'predict.fea.fullnerpair.onlyne.txt', '../data/vectors.nyt2011.cbow.semeval.filtered', '5', '0.005']
process = subprocess.Popen(test, cwd="fcm", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()

print() #sometimes it helps
```

Note that I'm already running another exe with similar code and it works
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it

I don't know exactly what is going on but the problem is with the `process.wait()`, I just deleted it and replaced the `Popen` function with the `run` fonction and it works

The difference between those two is that `popen` allows the script to run immediatly after you call it by creating a process, while using `run` you have to wait for the task to end